# What is the correct name for posts made on twitter?

Tags: meaning, writing, internet, social-media

Well, I honestly tried to search for this but I drowned in twit* and tweet* results.

Should I write:

- "my tweet" or "my twit"?
- "I am tweetting" or "I am twitting" ("to twit" vs. "to tweet")?

Referring to messages on twitter.com, what are the differences in their usage and meaning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To **tweet** a **tweet**

Twitter.com prefers the noun Tweet to be capitalised but dictionaries have it without the capital T

- Please tweet this to your followers
- I was tweeting about Twitter yesterday

Oxford dictionaries:

[**tweet**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tweet):

> A posting made on the social media website Twitter:
>   he started posting tweets via his mobile phone to let his parents know he was safe <sub>Oxford Dictionaries.com</sub>

[**Twit**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twit):

> A silly or foolish person.
>   <sub>Oxford Dictionaries.com</sub>

Mostly used in British English

Comment: I don't get the part about “Twit is similar to idiot in British English”, could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @FX_: The meaning of twit is similar to idiot. http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=twit

Comment: @FX_ Google translator: twit - A silly or foolish person

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I asked. There are tricky differences and not very pleasant ones to ignore them. And I twitted me all the time before!

Comment: And why is "a Tweet" capitalized and "to tweet" not? Can I write "a tweet" and what is the difference with "a twit"?

Comment: Birds twitter, they make a lot of short sounds. But a twit is a fool/idiot/birdbrain. To capitalise the Tweet is not really necessary but something the makes of twitter prefer due to the brand name.

Comment: Should I understand that by writing "Twit me" [in my profile](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3085/vgv8) I wrote "Make an idiot from me"? Or what is the meaning of "Twit me"?

Comment: I think people would understand, but British people would laugh and others would say: "Why does he spell Tweet like that?"

Comment: @GennadyVaninГеннадийВанин: I suspect because Twitter the company claims a trademark on Twitter (the noun), but not on the verb (you can't trademark a verb, here in the UK at least).

Answer (score 13):

Twitter is a brand and, as such, you should follow the usage established by the brand itself. Looking at http://blog.twitter.com/,  I see they describe the messages as **Tweets** (singular: a Tweet), with a capital T, and the action of sending them as **tweeting** (verb: **to tweet**), no capitalization.

That rule should be followed until established usage starts to differ from what the brand proposes, either because people think it's silly (like writing Yahoo! with its exclamation mark all the time) or because they think it's ugly (I would personally not use a capital T for tweets, as it disrupts the standard rules of capitalization).

Comment: +1 Why they did not call it tweetter.com? I miss something. Was it intentional to make joke of others?  The "tweetter" and twitting are with double "t" while the "tweeting" with one, is it correct?

Comment: @vgv8: Probably because the brand/word "Twitter" is more likely a corruption of "atwitter": nervously concerned : excited <gossips atwitter with speculation — Time>. "To tweet", pre-Twitter, would have meant "to make a bird-like sound", roughly.

Answer (score 8):

It also depends on the level of formality of your writing. In the summer of 2010, the standards editor for the New York Times [declared the policy for the NYT](http://www.theawl.com/2010/06/new-york-times-bans-the-word-tweet):

> Except for special effect, we try to
>   avoid colloquialisms, neologisms and
>   jargon. And "tweet" – as a noun or a
>   verb, referring to messages on Twitter
>   – is all three. Yet it has appeared 18
>   times in articles in the past month,
>   in a range of sections.
>
> ...
>
> "Tweet" may be acceptable occasionally
>   for special effect. But let's look for
>   deft, English alternatives: use
>   Twitter, post to or on Twitter, write
>   on Twitter, a Twitter message, a
>   Twitter update. Or, once you've
>   established that Twitter is the
>   medium, simply use "say" or "write."

Comment: +1 thanks, a new headache about nothing

Answer (score -1):

Tweet is a noun so "my tweet" is correct. "I am twittering" is the correct verb. Note the word twit used on twitter has no relations to the British use of the word twit used for an idiot. The co-founder for Twitter explains twit or twittering is the sound a bird makes. http://www.bitrebels.com/social/is-it-twittering-or-tweeting/

Comment: The word *twit* is by no means limited to the Isle of Britain.